# Get the Extent of a one center point

Tags: vue.js, openlayers

I tried to compute the extent with a one single point in the center of it

I tried with the boundingExtent method but it doesnt work. The computed extent is a single point not really an extent.

How can I do that ?

Thanks :)

Comment: In the center of what?  If your point is the center of a circle you would need the extent of the circle.

Comment: You can also buffer a point extent https://openlayers.org/en/main/apidoc/module-ol_extent.html#.buffer

Comment: @Mike I have several points in my map and I just want move the extent in order to have the chosen point on the center of the extent.

When I use boundingExtent, the extent zoom in my point and dont even see the other points of the map.

Answer (score 0):

If you want an extent centered on point `[x, y]` but also containing the extent `[x1, y1, x2, y2]` of all other features I think you would need to calculate it

```
var halfWidth = Math.max(Math.abs(x - x1), Math.abs(x - x2));
var halfHeight = Math.max(Math.abs(y - y1), Math.abs(y - y2));

var extent = [x - halfWidth, y - halfHeight, x + halfWidth, y + halfHeight];
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you will get an idea from the source code which was implemented in C# by me.

```
    public static List<Coordinate> GetExtentFromCenterCoordinate(Coordinate center, double distance_km)
    {
        double hypotenuse_each_quardilator = Math.Sqrt(Math.Pow((distance_km / 2), 2) + Math.Pow((distance_km / 2), 2)); //Hy = Sqrt(L2 + h2)
        double rad_angle = (Math.PI / 180) * 45;
        double distance = hypotenuse_each_quardilator / 100;

        //left-top
        double x1 = center.X - distance * Math.Cos(rad_angle);
        double y1 = center.Y + distance * Math.Sin(rad_angle);
        //right-top
        double x2 = center.X + distance * Math.Cos(rad_angle);
        double y2 = center.Y + distance * Math.Sin(rad_angle);
        //right-bottom
        double x3 = center.X + distance * Math.Cos(rad_angle);
        double y3 = center.Y - distance * Math.Sin(rad_angle);
        //left-bottom
        double x4 = center.X - distance * Math.Cos(rad_angle);
        double y4 = center.Y - distance * Math.Sin(rad_angle);

        List<Coordinate> extent_area = new List<Coordinate>();
        extent_area.Add(new Coordinate(x1, y1));//left-top
        extent_area.Add(new Coordinate(x2, y2));//right-top
        extent_area.Add(new Coordinate(x3, y3));//right-bottom
        extent_area.Add(new Coordinate(x4, y4));//left-bottom

        return extent_area;
    }
```